# Fail to load php module macports

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, macports

I'm trying to install `php` module via `macports`. I have them installed, so I run

```
cd /opt/local/apache2/modules
sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apxs -a -e -n "php5" mod_php54.so
```

Then I'll ensure myself, it's loaded, I see in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/mod_php54.so
```

Then I can see `php54.so` file exists in `modules` directory.
Then I restart the apache with below command:
`sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k restart`
But when I send query to load modules with `apachectl -M` command, I can't see any `php5` entry. Also, `.php` files aren't interpreted now, I can only see the sources.

What was my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote comprehensive instructions [here](http://muddledramblings.com/rumblings-from-the-secret-labs/lamp-server-from-scratch-with-macports/), but the main thing is that you need to make further edits to httpd.conf to tell it how to interpret `.php` files and to use `index.php`.

The key lines are

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

and

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

There's a lot more at the referenced link, along with long-winded explanations of every step.